# How to Limit Input from Edit Text of Range in 1895 to 2021

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I needs to limit the input in range of 1895 to 2021. So, I did this. But this didn't working. Any solutions for this matter.
I created a class NumberRange by implementing the InputFilter

```
package com.coderx.assignment02test;

import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;

public class NumberRange implements InputFilter {
    private long min;
    private long max;

    public NumberRange(long min, long max){
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public NumberRange(String min, String max){
       // this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
       // this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
        this.min = Long.parseLong(min);
        this.max = Long.parseLong(max);
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, Spanned spanned, int i2, int i3) {
        try {

            long input= Long.parseLong(spanned.toString() + charSequence.toString());
            if (inRange(min,max,input)){
                return null;
            }

        }catch (NumberFormatException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return "";
    }

    private boolean inRange(long a, long b, long c){
        return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }
}
```

Then, set the filter to editText

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new NumberRange("1895","2021")});
```

But it didn't allow to user to enter a number ?
How to fix this issue ?

Comment: Agree with Gabe's answers . Also u can consider some other widgets to get the input in this case may a `Spinner` or `NumberPicker` .

Answer (score 0):

Use the TextWatcher Library on Android.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

in the onTextChanged block give the number validation to keep it between 1895 and 2021.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is going to be that in order to type, say 1900, you need to type 1.  Which would run the validation and fail it.  So then you'd type 9, but since 1 failed it won't be 19 but 9.  Which will also fail.  And so on and so forth.

The best way to do validation for something like this is to do it in an onFocus handler and validate when the field loses focus, because then the entire text it typed.  A TextWatcher or InputFilter is problematic when you can't do letter by letter validation.